Is it preferable to use PySpark/SparkR in-built API functions over SQL queries for Databricks?
I am currently working on Databricks (using SparkR, but I'd imagine my question is still relevant for PySpark). I have a general question about whether there is a performance difference in using inbuilt Spark API functions over SQL queries. I tend to find the SQL query method a bit more intuitive and useful for adaptation and was under the impression that it should not change performance much, but someone has challenged me on that. What is the general consensus on this question? Or does it ultimately depend quite strongly on the specific data use case?
As an example, I have this fairly basic sparkR function which takes in a dataframe and groups the rows based on a column_name and a mapping list I provide. This is using SQL queries, there is obviously a way to do it using inbuilt functions, but does the performance really take a hit if you don't?
assign_categorical_groups <- function (input_data, column_name, specified_groups) {
  test_data <- input_data 
  # make the grouping list into a dataframe, with each category type having its group as an entry 
  grouping_df <- as.DataFrame(stack(specified_groups))
  names(grouping_df) <- c("category", "group")

  # broadcast the grouping_df for efficiency (since it should always be fairly small unless number of groups is egregious)
  grouping_df_bc <- broadcast(grouping_df)

  # create temporary views of both the data to categorise and the categories that it is to be placed into 
  createOrReplaceTempView(test_data, "dataset")
  createOrReplaceTempView(grouping_df_bc, "grouping_df")

  # write a SQL query to classify our data into the groups that are given in the correct column
  query <- paste("
                SELECT dataset.*, 
                CASE 
                  WHEN dataset.",column_name,"IS NULL THEN NULL
                  ELSE grouping_df.group
                END AS group
                FROM dataset 
                LEFT JOIN grouping_df 
                ON dataset.", column_name," == grouping_df.category")

  test_data  <- sql(query)

  return (test_data)
}


With a few exceptions they are equivalent.  The SQL is parsed into the same underlying Expression trees and query plans.
